# Problem wrapping .java to .exe using Launch4J but problem is likely version compliance

Tags: java, jar, javac, launch4j

I have a problem trying to wrap a java `.jar` as `.exe` and feel like I have checked out all there was on here which was remotely related. But I still couldn't get it to work. All the questions I found which seemed similar only concerned a part of my problem and also, the solution didn't work for me (such as this [Convert .jar to .exe using launch4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673036/convert-jar-to-exe-using-launch4j) or this [The compiler compliance specified is 1.6 but a JRE 1.8 is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372006/the-compiler-compliance-specified-is-1-6-but-a-jre-1-8-is-used) and many more).

### The Problem

So, in my concrete case, I need to wrap a small program to a Windows `.exe` for an elderly person to use (I can't expect them to run a `.jar` file themselves). I'm trying to get everything to run on 1.0.8, so that's Java 8.
The errors I get are, on the one hand, that the resulting `.exe` doesn't work, throwing a class error (indicating that there's a problem with the compiler compliance) when trying to run it.
Later on, trying around, I also got a compiler compliance warning in Eclipse, so that's likely the problem.

Then I also get an error concerning `module-info.java`. Just deleting the contents of the file seems to help (in terms of Eclipse warnings) but the final result also doesn't work.
I saw that you need Java 9 to use `module-info.java`. What do I have to do with this? I couldn't find any helpful answers on here (or maybe I didn't understand them).

### What I've tried

I have both the JDK and JRE installed (enviroment var set to JRE). I tried a clean and rebuild (like suggested in a question I can't find anymore) but it didn't do anything.

I am not so famililar with Java and usually use Linux, so Windows problems are not so familiar to me. I have found myself a Windows machine to compile my program from (because there seem to have been Java version problems when using `Launch4J` under Linux, trying to get an `.exe`.)

**Edit:** If one of you can help me solve my problem under Linux, that would be my favourite kind of solution. I currently use Linux Mint 20 but I also have Ubuntu installed on a machine I can access.

In the end, I think my `Launch4J` problem is actually a pre-existing problem of my `.jar` file stemming from the errors outlined above which I'll sum up again below:

I have been trying around for ages but I always get

1. The warning: `The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 14 is used`
2. The error: `Syntax error on token "module", interface expected`

I think that I should have fixed the compliance (both in `Build Path` and `Compiler` in the Properties) but it still doesn't work and it seems I've tried all there is. The environment variable is set and all. (There also isn't a `javac.exe` in my folder in case that makes a difference? Someone said to download it again but it doesn't help. Also, I've tried it on the customer's computer. They had a `javac.exe` and the whole thing still didn't work altough throwing different errors.)

#### Contents of `module-info.java`

Regarding the module, as the asker of this question (["Syntax error on token "module", interface expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129181/syntax-error-on-token-module-interface-expected)) has nothing but

```
module NameOfMyThingy {
}
```

Maybe some of you can help - would appreciate it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using launch4j, I recommend that you take a look at jpackage, which is available in JDK 14 and 15.  See [Packaging Tool User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-overview.html).  Note that for Windows you will also need to download the [WiX toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/).